# In latest stable nginx ingress controller limit-rps annotation in ingress yaml does not work

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, nginx-ingress

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps` is not working in below yaml file.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-ingress2
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: "1" # not working
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: "test.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: ps-clusterip
            port:
              number: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

On the official docs, the [nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps:](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rate-limiting) is the number of requests accepted from a given IP each minute.

On your case, you may want to check your annotations:

```
annotations: {
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: "1"
  ...
}
```

If applicable you can consider [global rate limiting](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#global-rate-limiting) as well.